# Derivative of Kronecker product by vector in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, vector, vector-calculus

I'm struggling with the following problem. It is necessary to find the derivative expression with respect to the vector $u$:

$r(u,v)=[(u-v)(u-v)^T]\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}=[(u-v)\otimes (u-v)]\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$

If we use the results from the topic
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112634/derivative-of-kronecker-product-of-vector-with-itself, we get:

$\frac{dr}{du}=[(\big(I\otimes(v-u)\big) + \big((v-u) \otimes I\big))]\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$

When I try to figure out the bracketed expression using Mathematica, I get an error.
As far as I understand, something is wrong in the original formula, because the summed arrays have different dimensions.

I need help from more experienced professionals.
I would be glad and grateful for help.

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

u = {a, b, c};

v = {x, y, z};

KroneckerProduct[u - v, u - v] // MatrixForm;

(KroneckerProduct[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1}], v - u] + 
   TensorProduct[v - u, DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1}]]) // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Use `Dimensions` to diagnose the issue - your `KroneckerProduct` is dimension `{3, 9}` but the `TensorProduct` is dimension `{3, 3, 3}`.

Comment: @flinty and what can i do? I don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tricky thing to keep in mind is that in Mathematica a vector is always 1 dimensional, so it's not automatically treated as an `n` by `1` matrix. Because of this, the distinction between column and row vectors disappears and this affects some matrix operations.

For example, consider:

```
u = {a, b, c};
KroneckerProduct[u, IdentityMatrix[3]] // Dimensions
KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], u] // Dimensions
```

> {9, 3}

> {3, 9}

Because of the different dimensions, you can't add the two matrices. Instead, turn `u` into a column vector explicitly:

```
u = List /@ {a, b, c};
KroneckerProduct[u, IdentityMatrix[3]] // Dimensions
KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], u] // Dimensions
```

> {9, 3}

> {9, 3}

Now you can add the results together.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251079/derivative-matrix-by-vector-in-mathematica