# Derivative matrix by vector in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, vector, tensors, vector-calculus

This is an excerpt from the article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0094114X10000418.

How do I write this using vector-matrix operations (`TensorProduct` or `KroneckerProduct` or *other*) in Mathematica?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D[A,{X}]` will do it because `D` already operates on all elements of the matrix and the `{X}` argument (grad) will differentiate w.r.t each part of `X`. But you'll need to flatten each row to get the form you want:

```
n = 2; m = 3;
X = Array[x, n]
A = Array[a[#1, #2] @@ X &, {n, m}];

(Flatten /@ D[A, {X}]) // MatrixForm
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I need a formal mathematical description of this operation, is it possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If anything the maths you've shown is less formal than Mathematica as it loosely inserts vectors into a matrix becoming a bigger matrix of scalars instead of a NxM matrix of vectors. The flattening is like $\text{vec}(...)$.

Comment: @dtn the Tensor product and Kronecker product are not relevant here.

Comment: @dtn Only `Grad` or $\nabla$ as this is applied to every entry in the matrix.

Comment: `Rx = RotationMatrix[\[Phi][t], {1, 0, 0}];`

`Ry = RotationMatrix[\[Xi][t], {0, 1, 0}];`

`Rz = RotationMatrix[\[Psi][t], {0, 0, 1}];`

`Q = Rz.Ry.Rx;`

`v = {\[Phi][t], \[Xi][t], \[Psi][t]};`

Comment: @dtn it's just `Flatten /@ D[Q, {v}]` ??